# How can I start flyway migration before hibernate validation?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, flyway

I use flyway + hibernate validate. I have flyway bean:

```
@Component
public class DbMigration {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DbMigration.class);

    private final Config config;

    @Autowired
    public DbMigration(Config config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public void runMigration() {
        try {
            Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
            flyway.configure(properties());
            int migrationApplied = flyway.migrate();
            LOG.info("[" + migrationApplied + "] migrations are applied");
        } catch (FlywayException ex) {
            throw new DatabaseException("Exception during database migrations: ", ex);
        }
    }

    public Properties properties() {
        //my prop
    }
}
```

And in Apllication class I do it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfiguration.class);
            context.getBean(DbMigration.class).runMigration();
```

But my hibernate start before `runMigration();` And validate throw exeption. How can I start next?

1. run Migration
2. start hibernate validation

EDIT:

```
  @Bean
    @Autowired
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource datasource) {
        log.info("entityManagerFactory start");
        dbMigration.runMigration();
```

But I think it is bad

Comment: Are you using `spring-boot`? if so you don't need to define a component for flyway migration. If you want override the default options and make it run before hibernate add a bean configuration like I explained in my answer. You don't need to tell spring-boot to run the migration, it does it automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your spring application configuration, if you have an entity manager factory bean configuration you can make it depend on the flyway bean so that it gets initialized after it. Something like:

```
@Bean
@DependsOn("flyway")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    // Initialize EntityManagerFactory here
}
```

The `flyway` bean configuration can be something like:

```
@Bean(initMethod = "migrate")
public Flyway flyway() {
    Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
    // configure bean here
    return flyway;
}
```

Comment: yes I have LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean  where I get "flyway"?

Comment: "flyway" is the name of your flyway bean. You can configure it like you do `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. I'll add an example to  my answer.

Comment: This is a great solution if you only have on `Flyway` instance. In my project, each module has it's own `Flyway` instance to manage their tables themselves and now having the same problem. How could the initialization problem solved with that given situation?